# Create Multiple DataRelations between three tables in DataSet (Not Strongly Typed)

Tags: c#, .net, dataset, datarelation

I am familiar with programmatically loading a dataset with two tables and adding a parent child relationship between them.

When I tried adding a third table and a second relationship in the same DataSet, I get unexpected results.

I what I am trying to do possible? If so, is there an example? (I have googled but no good results)

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: This question isn't really related to asp.net - consider removing that tag.

Comment: As ususal, after posting a question I find an answer... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6s958d6%28VS.71%29.aspx